# Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google form to enter data and the Form Responses Sheet open.  On a second sheet I want to pull certain data from the Responses sheet based on criteria.  Below is my function. And my error.

Function:
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:U,"SELECT Col5,Col8,Col9,Col12,Col10,Col11,Col6 WHERE Col2 CONTAINS 'Kindergarten'")

Error:
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Answer (score 3):

`=QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A:U},"SELECT Col5,Col8,Col9,Col12,Col10,Col11,Col6 WHERE Col2 CONTAINS 'Kindergarten'")`

It would usually be the notation `"select E,G,H,K,L,F` but to use `Col1` etc, wrap `{}` around the range.