# How to add to query with 2nd parameter

Tags: google-sheets

I am using...
=QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A2:U},"SELECT Col5,Col8,Col9,Col12,Col10,Col11,Col6 WHERE Col2 CONTAINS 'Kindergarten' AND Col4 CONTAINS 'No'")

I want to pull all 'Kindergarten' rows from Col2.  Col4 includes Yes or No and I only want to include the 'No' rows from Col4.  But above is not working.

Comment: What isn't working ? What is the error you get? Can you share a (copy of) your spreadsheet so we can get a closer look?

Comment: It's not giving me an error, it's just still pulling rows that include the Yes in Col4.

Comment: A single row? More?  Try changing the last part to ... AND Col4 CONTAINS 'No'", 0) and see if that helps?

Comment: Please share a sample test sheet. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's related to [Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536969/error-unable-to-parse-query-string-for-function-query-parameter-2-no-column-co)

We can't see your data, but just in case the issue is with partial matching or capitalisation, try this:

`=QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A2:U},"SELECT Col5,Col8,Col9,Col12,Col10,Col11,Col6 WHERE lower(Col2) like '%kindergarten%' AND lower(Col4) like '%no%'",0)`

Please also consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers so we can determine how the answers match your questions.

[image]